# redirect users from registration page drupal via apache directive

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal

I want to strongly discourage users from accessing a specific page in Drupal.
I cannot do via configuration. Can it be done via apache redirect in htaccess file? 
or other technique?

example

```
http://example.com/lang/user/register
```

redirect to

```
http://172.19.0.31/lang/pageNotFound
```

however if they type

```
http://example.com/lang/user/SecreditRegisterPage
```

they will get

```
http://example.com/lang/user/register
```

Comment: This is entirely possible to achieve with Drupal itself if you write your own module. Are you open to that or were you looking for a way to handle it in Drupal without writing any code?

Comment: Prefer via apache cconfig if possible; I have seen articles on creating Magento module; Wpuld like to avoid custom drupal work as effort and support effort are larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't think u can use a redirect rule with your scenario cause it would create a redirect loop eg secretregister redirects to user/register which redirects to pagenotfound

But there are contributed drupal modules that you can use to easily change the default drupal paths eg [Rename Admin Paths](https://drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths)

also from security perspective and to avoid spambots, captcha module would be helpfull at least for user registration page